# tsconfig.json: Cannot find type definition file for 'json-schema 2'

Tags: reactjs, json, typescript, tsconfig

I have built a react front-end but after my most recent commit I am now seeing this error message on my tsconfig.json file:

"Cannot find type definition file for 'json-schema 2'.
The file is in the program because:
Entry point for implicit type library 'json-schema 2'"

This is the first time I have seen this error and it also shows when I npm start, however it seems to still allow me to view the local front-end after a few minutes??

I am using tsx components to make up my app with JSONs for data that I render.

Here is what my tsconfig.json looks like:

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "target": "esNext",
    "lib": ["esNext", "DOM", "dom.iterable"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "paths": {
        "@modules/*": ["src/modules/*"],
        "@components/*": ["src/components/*"],
        "@utils/*": ["src/utils/*"],
        "@misc/*": ["src/misc/*"],
        "@assets/*": ["src/assets/*"],
        "@declarations/*": ["src/declarations/*"],
    }
},
"exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
```

}

If anyone has seen this error before or knows how it can be resolved that would be hugely appreciated. Thanks!